# react router 4 - multiple path matching with dynamic params

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I've tried React Router 4 with regex path matching but I couldn't get it to work. I thought I could do something like this:

`<Route path='/(|blogs/:id)/' render={(props) => (<BlogCategory {...props} />)}/>`

Basically, match the default path `/` and this path: `/blogs/:id` and render using the same **BlogCategory** component where I'll be extracting the `:id` by using `this.props.match.params.id`

I've found alternate ways to match the 2 paths from above but they're less elegant. So the question is, how do you use the same component with multiple paths matched by regex, some of which might have dynamic params?